# Code Executing in different orders, Jframe, Button and TextArea

Tags: java, swing, jframe, awt, jtextfield

Basically i have some code to make an interface that allows me to submit a request and it pulls the necessary information from a txt File. For some reason wheni execute my StartUp for the code, sometimes the button isnt there, one text box dominates the screen, all the textboxes overlap... Its weird.

Anyway heres the GUI Code

```
public class Menu {

SubmitCode submit = new SubmitCode();

    public static JFrame frame;
    public static JTextField field;
    public static Button btn;
    public static TextArea txtComm;
    public static TextArea txtSites;
    public static TextArea txtProg;
    public static Dimension dim = new Dimension(40, 10);

    public Menu() {
        frame = new JFrame();

        frame.setTitle("Welcome :)");
        frame.pack();
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    }

    public static void open()   {
        Menu.main(null);    // Opens up the main method of the class
    }

    public static void main(String args[])  {
        field = new JTextField();
        btn = new Button();
        txtComm = new TextArea();
        txtSites = new TextArea();
        txtProg = new TextArea();

        field.setText("What do you want to do?");
        field.setSize(390, 20);
        field.setLocation(0, 125);

        btn.setVisible(true);
        btn.setLabel("Click to Submit");
        btn.setSize(90, 20);
        btn.setLocation(400, 125);

        txtComm.setVisible(true);
        txtComm.setText("Commands: ");
        txtComm.setSize(150, 100);
        txtComm.setLocation(10, 10);
        txtComm.setEditable(false);
        frame.add(txtComm);

        txtSites.setVisible(true);
        txtSites.setText("Sites: ");
        txtSites.setSize(150, 100);
        txtSites.setLocation(170, 10);
        txtSites.setEditable(false);
        frame.add(txtSites);

        txtProg.setVisible(true);
        txtProg.setText("Programmes: ");
        txtProg.setSize(150, 100);
        txtProg.setLocation(330, 10);
        txtProg.setEditable(false);
        frame.add(txtProg);

        frame.setSize(500, 175);
        frame.add(field, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.add(btn);

        btn.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                System.out.println("Do Something Clicked");

                SubmitCode.main(null);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Suggestions:

- Don't use static methods/fields, except when a specific need arises or for the main method. You do not have the need here.
- Instead use valid classes, classes with constructors, instance (non-static) fields and instance methods.
- Don't needlessly mix AWT and Swing components but instead use just Swing components. So JTextArea, not TextArea, JButton, not Button, etc....
- For instance, your Menu constructor is wasted code that is never called due to your misuse and over-use of statics.
- Don't set sizes, use null layouts and absolute positioning such as with setBounds.
- Instead read up on and use the layout managers.
- Don't pepper your code with useless bits such as most of your calls to `setVisible(true)`.
- Call `setVisible(true)` on the top level window, here your JFrame, *after* adding all components.
- Do read the relevant tutorials as this is all very well explained there. Google Java [Swing Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html) and check the very first hit.
- This bit scares me: `SubmitCode.main(null);` and suggests that you're trying to call the static main method of another class from within a GUI. You should avoid doing this, and instead have your SubmitCode class use good OOP techniques including non-static methods and fields, constructors, etc...

Comment: Thanks, I'm quite new and these are soem very helpful tips, i assumed i would need to instantaniate some of my variables as Static, and i thought setVisible had to be applied to all components, much appreciated

Comment: @user3200016: Please try [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html) instead.